# How to use Combobox with dictionnary

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I try to reproduce a list as we can do in html

```
<select id="monselect">
  <option value="valeur1">Valeur 1</option> 
  <option value="valeur2" selected>Valeur 2</option>
  <option value="valeur3">Valeur 3</option>
</select>
```

in python 3, I should have something like that :

```
mydict = {´value1':'abc', 'value2':'qwe'}

combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.frame, values=list(mydict.values()), textvariable=selected, width=70)
combobox.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=NSEW)
```

it will print a box with 'abc' and 'qwe'
How can i only keep the value 'value1´ or 'value2' store in the combobox ?

Comment: Its quite unclear what your asking for.

Comment: i want to have a value different from the name display.
In html it's quite clear, when you select "Valeur 1" you get 'value1' and not the display name

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, what you're looking for can be achieved by simply indexing the dictionary, with the selected value from combobox, take a look:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

def selected():
    val = mydict[combobox.get()] #index the dict
    print(val)

mydict = {'value1':'abc', 'value2':'qwe'}

combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(mydict.keys()), width=70)
combobox.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

Button(root,text='Click me',command=selected).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Notice here that I switched `list(mydict.values())` with `list(mydict.keys())`, it is because you can only index a dictionary by the key of the dictionary. If you want the values of the dictionary to show up in the `combobox` then you can simply interchange the name of keys and values or you could use dictionary comprehension, like:

```
mydict = {v:k for (k,v) in mydict.items()}
```

With this, key and value of the dictionary will be switched.

Comment: thank you taking time to answer
It's quite different from php/html but I understood the way to do it
Thanks again ;)

Comment: @f42 ~ Would appreciate marking this as the correct answer. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to see how to mark as the answer.